# ui:repeat to render list of panelMenu

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

i have a bean that return a List of DefaultMenuModel.
I want to do something like that:

```
<h:form>
   <ui:repeat var="_menuModel" value="#{indicadorManager.listPanelMenu}">
       <p:panelMenu model="#{_menuModel}" />
   </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

The problem is when i click on items that ui:repeat created. I'm not redirected to the page.

This one works:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelMenu model="#{indicadorManager.listPanelMenu.get(0)}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that i found:

```
<h:form>
    <c:forEach var="mm" items="#{indicadorManager.listPanelMenu}">
        <p:panelMenu model="#{mm}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```